# Postgresql NpgSql connection handling extra query and multiple close connection

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I am basically running a sql query through dapper but when I do some profiling on this on every query that i perform to npg sql I see an extra `ExecuteScalar` query that is sent on that connection. And there are multiple `NpgsqlConnection.Close` events. I run the query in a using statement that terminates the `NpgsqlConnection` as follow.

```
        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            return connection.QueryAsync<T>(sql, param);
        }
```

The but it also runs this extra command one every sql that i send through this code -

```
SET extra_float_digits = 3
SET ssl_renegotiation_limit = 0
SET lc_monetary = 'C'
SELECT 'Npgsql73113'
```

Here is the profiler screenshot of the relevant section. Any one know why there is this extra query and multiple Connection Close events.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using Npgsql 2.2, which is very old by now and which sent these commands on startup. Please upgrade to the latest stable version (3.1.3) and these should be gone.

I'm less sure about the connection close events, if you see this behavior in 3.1.3 please report an issue.